# Изменение текста при помощи кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня не получается изменять текст при нажатии на кнопку. Раньше я делал так:`<input type='button' value='Изменить текст' onclick='test.innerText = "Он поменялся!"'>`, но нужно делать таким способом.

```html
        <button1 onclick= Test.innerText = "Чтоо">
            Описание1
        </button1>


        <br>
        <p id = "Test">
            Тест
        </p>
```

Как менять текст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните значение атрибута в двойные кавычки, а строку в одинарные

```html
<button onclick="Test.innerText = 'Чтоо'">
  Описание1
</button>


<br>

<p id="Test">Тест</p>
```

---

А лучше делать как все современные люди:

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#Test').innerText = 'Чтоо';
});
```

```html
<button onclick="Test.innerText = 'Чтоо'" id="btn">
    Описание1
</button>


<br>

<p id="Test">Тест</p>
```